# Binary search tree method needed: find minimum value node

Tags: java, recursion, iterator

Anyone could help me do this: I need a public method for my binary search tree ADT that returns a reference to the information in the node with the smallest value in the tree. The signature of the method is:

public T min()

A. Design an interative version of the method.

B. Design a reccursive version of the method.

C. Which approach is better? Explain please.

This is not a HW or anything, its a practice for myself.

Comment: So in your iterative solution, you'll use loops to determine when you've reached the left most node. In your recursive solution, you'll keep calling the min() method until you get to the smallest solution. Then, to work out which is better, work out how many steps each solution takes.

Comment: Have you coded BST class ?

Comment: @RicardoCacheira yes bro.

Comment: @RicardoCacheira ricardo, edited with what i tried doing, could you check the solutions? and give your feedback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i think that if i gave you the solution you will not learn, i'll give a link to you read more about Binary Search Tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

After that comment, My way:

```
public T min() {
    return recMin(root).getInfo();
}

public BSTnode<T> recMin(BSTnode<T> tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    if (tree.left == null) {
        return tree;
    }
    return recMin(tree.left);
}

public T IterationMin(BSTnode<T> tree) {
    if (tree == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    while (tree.left != null) {
        tree = tree.left;
    }
    return tree.getInfo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A binary search tree has a lower value to the left always, correct?  So, you should always go left when you can.  If you can't, then you've reached the lowest value.

Comment: +1: However, just to nitpick, a binary search tree always has lower values to left - not a binary tree.

Comment: @AndrewMartin exactly, here im working with binary search trees. I dont know how to do this.

Comment: @user2272227: Joel is right, I was just nitpicking about the search tree part. Your tree is organised so the smallest values are to the left with the largest values to the right. So you want to develop a method which keeps looking to the left, as Joel said, until it can't go any further.

Comment: @AndrewMartin andrew, edited the post with my code of both versions, could you check and give your feedback?

Comment: For the recursive solution you posted above, you are casting a `BSTNode` to type `T`. This will fail, go ahead and use your `getInfo()` method on the returned BSTNode.

Conceptually I think you have the right idea for both. But finding the minimum node is trivial only if the tree is built properly. I'd suggest writing an `Add` method to solidify your understanding of how BST's are structured.

Comment: @Porkbutts already have the add method and know how it works. what about the iteration method? take a look at it please and give a feedback? thanks!

Comment: so i replace the (T) recMin(root) to     return recMin(root).getInfo();

Comment: Iterative is correct.  Recursive needs to return the info, not the node, and check for a null tree.

Comment: @Joel could i just check in the reccursive method if the root is null then throw the exception and if not, just return recMin(root.left); or do i have to also check for the root.left?

Comment: You should just need to check if root is null.  Think very hard about why

Comment: @Joel i know but about if it's not and there are no nodes except the root?

Comment: Your code disappeared, but if I remember right, you call minRecursive(root), right?  In which case, it will just return root, and you can getinfo from there.

Answer (score 2):

On the matter of whether iterative or recursive is better. It really depends. In general recursive solutions tend to be easier to understand, but slower since they consume more and more stack space proportional to the depth of recursion. In this case however, you can come up with a tail-recursive solution which should be easy to understand and just as efficient as the iterative solution.

```
public BSTNode<T> findMin(BSTNode<T> node) {
    if (node.left == null)     // if there is no left, we are done
        return node;
    return findMin(node.left); // recursively search on the left-child
}
```

Start by calling this method on the head node.

Comment: I would say in this instance that both recursive and iterative would be roughly the same, as they'll both require the same number of comparisons to be made to reach the smallest value (although I agree with what you say about them usually being slower).

Comment: pork, that will do everything?

Comment: @user2272227: That will recursively work towards finding the smallest node (i.e. the smallest value). If your binary tree works and the smallest value is stored in the left most node, that will return it. You still need an iterative solution.

Comment: @AndrewMartin check code in main post, just edited and added.

Comment: @user2272227: Out of curiosity, why can't you test? You need more than the code you posted to test, such as a comparator method to determine if two nodes are equal.

Comment: @AndrewMartin stupid PC won't give me a compilation ;s but what do u think of the code? the reccursive one you gave me?

Comment: @user2272227: Porkbutts code to recursively find the smallest looks good. However, as I said, it's assuming you have a comparison method somewhere which will compare the contents of the search tree and know to keep going left. You need to code that somewhere. Check out the wiki link for some guidance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: @AndrewMartin what about the iteration code? and hmm how can i check for the equals? are you able to do it?

Comment: @user2272227: Just google an example, there are hundreds online. It's a very common data structure.